# SmoothScrollTo item in RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, android-nestedscrollview

**This is my layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/nsvRoot"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <More_Child_Views/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <More_Child_Views/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvItems"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is a `RecyclerView` at the bottom of this layout with id `rvItems`.

I want the root `NestedScrollView` to scroll to the position of a particular item in this `Recyclerview`.

**I tried:**

> rvItems.getChildAt(itemIndex).getY();

but `childAt(itemIndex)` returns **null**, `rvItems.getItemCount()` returns **0**, even when there is 15+ items showing in the recyclerview.

I assume this is due to the `NestedScrollView` as parent of `RecyclerView`.
How can I scroll to the position of item in the `recyclerView`?

Comment: post your adapter code

Answer (score 0):

**Few notes**

Please show us how you declare/setup your adapters and recyclerviews. Also do checks on your end the order of method invocation/s. (eg. setup adapter first before passing it to recyclerview).

**What could possibly solve this**

```java
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(10); // 10 being the position of the item
```

**Read more on**

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#scrolltoposition